# How to load content without refresh with multiple querystring

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to load a dynamic content to specific div name with multiple querystring from a menu.

Example dynamic menu link

```
index.php?tag=2
index.php?category=1&tag=2
index.php?category=2&tag=2&location=3
```

Example query process in PHP for link `index.php?category=1&tag=2`

```
$tag = intval($_GET['tag']);
$cat = intval($_GET['category']);

if(isset($tag) && isset($cat)) {
$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat=".$cat." AND tag=".$tag."");
... // fetch results
}
```

Question - With jQuery how to tell user clicked the link then send the callback to PHP process & show the results in the specific div name without refresh the page.

Let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Description

1. You have to create another php page that returns data in json format for the given substring. Your substring is dynamic so you have to get the substring from another element. I suggest a `<input type="hidden" value="YourQueryString"/>`, its simple. You can put the element next to your link and get the value using `jQuery.val()`.
2. Then you use `jQuery.ajax()` / `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.post()` in your index.php to get the data from that page / script. (`jQuery.get()` and `jQuery.post()` uses `jQuery.ajax()` internally)
3. In the callback method of jQuery ajax you grab the data and build the html from it.
   After that you can use [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the data to your div.

## Sample

**html / php**

```
<a class="AnyClassName">Click me</a>
<input type="hidden" value="category=1&tag=2"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".AnyClassName").click(function() {
    // lets get the query string
    var queryString = $(this).next().val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourNewPage.php?" + queryString,
      context: document.body,
      success: function(data){
        var generatedHtml = "..." // build your html from the data object
        $("#IdOfYourDiv").html(generatedHtml);
      }
    });
});
```

## Update

Alternatively your php page can return html (simple page) for your query string. This is easier than build html in the `jQuery Ajax Callback`. If this is done you can do this

```
$(".AnyClassName").click(function() {
    // lets get the query string
    var queryString = $(this).next().val();
    $('#IdOfYourDiv').load("yourNewPage.php?" + queryString);
});
```

### More Information

**Documentation**

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [jQuery.post()](http://docs.jquery.com/Post)
- [jQuery.get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Get#.24.get.28.29_-_Data_transfer_method)
- [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)
- [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [jQuery.val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Val)
- [jQuery.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

**Tutorials**

- [jQuery, Ajax, Json and Php](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php)
- [Use jQuery and PHP to build an Ajax-driven Web page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks dknaack. You made me on the track. Question, on the `url:"yourNewPage.php?category=1&tag=2"` how to make it be dynamic? Let's say I'm click on `index.php?category=2&tag=2&location=3`.

Answer (score 4):

Use one of jQueries many AJAX functions, for instance:

```
  $.post("ajax.php", "category=1&tag=2",
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Check:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP script should return the HTML you want to load into the div; the JS looks like this:

```
$('#your_menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      url = $this.href;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(html) {
      $('#div_to_update').html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

It gets the URL from the link you clicked in the menu, passes the URL to the Ajax call, and fills the target div with the HTML response. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info on this topic.

Comment: hmmmm link with no explanation... Sir you are asking to be downvoted.

Comment: I think everything he needs is behind that link, but ok. I took this as a "where do I even begin" question.

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow are meant to be self-contained. Links are fine as long as they're accompanied by explanations, sample code, and/or quotes from what is being linked to. This would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.load()` for this (Javascript - client side):

```
$('#id_of_the_div').load('index.php?category=1&tag=2');
```

Check out the http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more.